# How to access param value in my server controller?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

```
app.controller('UserOthersListCtrl', ['$http','$scope', '$stateParams', 'userOthers','$compile', '$state','DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnBuilder',
 function($http, $scope, $stateParams, userOthers, $compile, $state,    DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder)

{

var vm = this;

vm.dtInstance = {};
vm.users = [];
console.log("user", $stateParams.id);
vm.page = $stateParams.page;

vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()

   .withOption('ajax', {
       url: '/users/others/list/id',
       type: 'post',
        data: function(data, dtInstance) {


           console.log(data);
       }


    })
```

I want to pass the value of id using the url but when i am using the above code and debug its shows id as text and i can't access the value of id in my server side controller

Answer (score 0):

Your URLs didn't include the value for the id. You need to build you url to include the id as follows.

```
.withOption('ajax', {
   url: '/users/others/list/' + $stateParams.id,
   type: 'post',
    data: function(data, dtInstance) {
       console.log(data);
   }
})
```